# Pass Java HashMap to Lua script

Tags: java, lua, luaj

I want to pass a Java HashMap to a Lua script from Java code in LuaJ. But all I see is we have `chunk.call()` and `chunk.invoke()` where we can pass the arguments or array of `LuaValue.valueOf()`, which allow us either int, byte, double, string and boolean.

Comment: Lua doesn't interact with Java. Are you perhaps using LuaJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`LuaValue.tableOf()`](http://luaj.org/luaj/3.0/api/org/luaj/vm2/LuaValue.html#tableOf()) to create an empty table. You can then call [`LuaValue.set`](http://luaj.org/luaj/3.0/api/org/luaj/vm2/LuaValue.html#set(org.luaj.vm2.LuaValue,%20org.luaj.vm2.LuaValue)) to insert your HashMap entries. Example:

```java
LuaValue table = LuaValue.tableOf();
// assuming map is a HashMap of the "primitive" Lua types valueOf supports
for (Entry e : map.entrySet())
    table.set(LuaValue.valueOf(e.getKey()), LuaValue.valueOf(e.getValue()));
```